# Can I poll a workspace repository that is located in the slave (Jenkins+RTC plugin)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent, rational-team-concert

I recently started working in a way for speeding up the building time of a relatively big software code base of my company. This code base is using RTC for source code management and after looking and trying I ended using jenkins for automation of the process. I started by creating my build server in a local machine and configure the repository through the RTC plugin, which works quite well using the poll SCM option and with the workspace repository-rtc option. However, I have to move this job to the official jenkins company server, but keeping the job execution in the original local PC. I have added the PC as a jenkins node and I have not had any problem with reaching it through jenkins, but my question/assumptions are the following:

It looks like the job is executing the RTC buildtoolkit from the slave (or at least I had to configured the RTC path in the node.
For some reason, it looks like the polling in jenkins is always looking for the repository in the master, even when I add a SCM pre step in which I can validate that the job is running in the slave system.

My question: Is there any way of ensuring the polling happening in the slave (without scripting or adding external solutions, just using RTC plugin)? For security reason I cannot add additional plugins to Jenkins or to create anything in the master, I only got a free job to configure.

Comment: You can force a job to be executed on a specific node in its configuration. Look for restrict this job. Isn't that enough?

Comment: The job is being executed in the node I want (or at least I checked that by traversing in the PC through build steps and pre scm). The problem is that the polling is not finding the workspace. I am using the same workspace that I used with a local jenkins installation. However, RTC is throwing the error that it cannot locate the workspace.